# Update one name of data from one column, all data that have same name and in the same column will also updated

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help, i have a table named POSITION. the columns for this table are p_no, p_name and p_training_type. p_name is stand for position name.. one p_name will attend many type of training, for example it can be like this

### p_no  |p_name              |  p_training_type

1    |GENERAL MANAGER     |  sea survival
 2    |GENERAL MANAGER     |  safety driving
 3    |TECHNICAL ASSISTANT |  sea survival
 4    |HSSE MANAGER        |  sea survival

what i want to do is by update one p_name example GENERAL MANAGER, all the p_name which hav the same p_name also will change..for example, the user will search the p_name that they want to update in update1.php page, but the user not remember the full name of the position name.. so the user will typing MANAGER.. so the result are.

1. GENERAL MANAGER
2. HSSE MANAGER

next, user will click the position name that they want to update..for example the user click at GENERAL MANAGER.

so the position name will be carry to another page(update2.php) where the GENERAL MANAGER will in the form that can be edit. after edit the name by typing the GENERAL MANAGER as ADMIN MANAGER n click update button.. it will go to update3.php, where in this page it contain update query.

For the result, there is no error display.. but the data stil not update which is still GENERAL MANAGER not ADMIN MANAGER. i don't know where the problem will be.. below are the related pages for update process..

**update1.php**

```
        <form action="update1.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
        <table><tr>
           <th scope="col"><span class="style1"></span>Type:</span></th>
           <th colspan="2"><select name="method">
              <option value="" selected>-Please choose-</option>
              <option value="position">By Position</option>
              <option value="training">By Training Type</option>
        </select></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th scope="col">Input Query :</th>
           <th><input type="text" id="search" name="search" size="50" /></th>
           <th><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Search" /></th>
        </tr></table>
        </form>

         <?php  $resultName=$_POST['search']; ?>   

<?php

$search =$_POST['search'];
$method =$_POST['method'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("training", $con);

if($method=="") 
    { 
     }

else if($method=="position"){    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT distinct p_name FROM test WHERE p_name LIKE '%$search%'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
}

else if($method=="training"){    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT distinct p_training_type FROM test WHERE p_training_type LIKE '%$search%'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
} 


echo "<font  size=2>"." Total number of result found for "."<font color='#FF0000' size=2>".$resultName."<font color='#43423F' size=2>"." :"."<font color='#FF0000' size=2>"." $num_rows"."<font color='#43423F' size=2>";
?>
<div
style="border: 0px; width: 620px; height: 400px; overflow: auto;">     
<?php
echo "<table width='600' height='0' border='0' bordercolor='#000000' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
<tr>
   <th bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'>Result </th>
   <th bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'>Action</th>
</tr>";

if($method!="") 
    {   

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  if($method=="position"){
   echo "<tr>
            <td height=0 bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>"."<font size=2>".$row['p_name']."</td>
        <td height=0 bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>"."<font size=2><a href='update2.php?p_name=$row[p_name]'><img src='edit.gif' title='Edit' /></a>
         <a href='delete2.php?valid=".$row['p_name']."'><img src='delete.gif' title='Delete' /></a></td>";}

 else if($method=="training"){
  echo "<tr><td height=0 bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>"."<font size=2>"."<input name='p_training_type' width='25' type='text' value='".$row['p_training_type']."'/>"."</td>";}
  }
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

**update2.php**

```
<table width="600" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Designation</th>
    <th width="17" scope="col">Action</th>
  </tr>
  <form name="form2"  method="POST" action="update3.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="p_name" type="text" id="p_name" value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetZ['p_name']; ?>" size="20" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Update" id="update" name="update"/></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
```

**update3.php**

```
<?php
$p_name=$_POST['p_name'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("training", $con);
{

$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE POSITION SET p_name='$p_name' WHERE p_name='".$p_name."'") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("The details are successfully insert")'; 
    print '</script>';

    mysql_close($con);

}

    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">{                                                                                         
    location.href=\"upate1.php\";                                                                                               
    }</script>";
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to main the `PID` through the hidden field on the form submit like

```
<form name="form2"  method="POST" action="update3.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <tr>
     <td><input name="p_id" type="hidden" id="p_id" value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetZ['p_id']; ?>" size="20" /></td>
     <td><input name="p_name" type="text" id="p_name" value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetZ['p_name']; ?>" size="20" /></td>
     <td><input type="submit" value="Update" id="update" name="update"/></td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

And the your submit query will be

```
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE POSITION 
                  SET p_name='$p_name' 
                  WHERE p_name='".$p_name."' AND p_id = '".$_POST['p_id']."'");
```

Comment: urmm.. but i want all GENERAL MANAGER in p_name column also will change as ADMIN MANAGER.. do u know how? T_T